# HackerRank Product Distribution

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, functional-programming

I have been trying to solve this challenge, and somewhat figured out what to do. But after all my attempts, I am able to pass only the test cases, and one more case in the Submit Panel. All fails after that

### Problem

A company has requested to streamline their product allocation strategy, and given n products, each of which has an associated value, you are required to arrange these products into segments for processing. There are infinite segments indexed as 1, 2, 3 and so on.

However, there are two constraints:

- You can assign a product to a segment with index i if and only if  i = 1 or the segment with index i-1 has at least m products.
- Any segment must contain either no products or at least m products.

The score for a segment is defined as the index of the segment multiplied by the sum of values of the products it contains. The score of an arrangement of products is the sum of scores of segments. Your task is to compute the maximum score of an arrangement.

Consider, for example, n = 11 products and m = 3. One optimal way to assign is -

1. Assign the first three products to segment 1.
2. Assign the next three products to segment 2.
3. Assign the next five products to segment 3.

Note that we can not assign 2 products to segment 4 as the second constraint would be violated. The score of the above arrangement is -

1 * (1 + 2 + 3) + 2 * (4 + 5 + 6) + 3 * (7 + 8 + 9 + 10 + 11) = 6 + 30 + 135 = 171.

Since the arrangement score can be very large, print it modulo 10^9 + 7.

**Input Format**

In the first line, there are two space-separated integers n and m.

In the second line, there are n space-separated integers a0,a1,....,an-1 denoting the values associated with the products.

**Constraints**

- 1 <= n <= 10^6
- 1 <= m <= n
- 1 <= ai <= 10^9

**Output Format**

In a single line, print a single integer denoting the maximum score of the arrangement modulo 10^9 + 7.

**Sample Input 0**

```
5 2
1 5 4 2 3
```

**Sample Output 0**

```
27
```

**Explanation 0**

The array is a = [1,5,4,2,3] and m = 2. It is optimal to put the first and fourth products into the first segment and the remaining products to the second segment. Doing that, we get the arrangement score (1+2) * 1 + (3+4+5) * 2 = 27 which is the greatest score that can be obtained. Finally, the answer is  modulo 10^9 + 7 which is 27.

**Sample Input 1**

```
4 4
4 1 9 7
```

**Sample Output 1**

```
21
```

**Explanation 1**

All the four products must be placed in the first segment. The score in this case will be 1 * (4 + 1 + 9 + 7) = 21.

### My solution

Now what I have figured out is explained in my algorithm:

1. To check if the array length == m, if yes, return the sum of all elements
2. If not, take start = 0 and end = m, as a pointer which will take care of the sum of the elements till that part `start -> end`
3. Sort the array for best results
4. Take batch = 1, which will be incremented in a while loop, and multiplied with the sum of the limited products array
5. For remaining elements in the array, do same operation `batch * (sum of elements from start till end)`
6. Add it to the maxSum and return the maxSum

**Code**

```
def maxScore(segment, products):
    # Write your code here
    # If the segment == products, then it should return all the sum
    # We will evaluate as per the products listing requirement and find the sum
    
    '''
        Algo for else condition
        1. We will maintain a start and end pointer to keep a check till counter equals products
        2. We will keep adding the maxSum of the value [i * sum(batch of the element)]
        3. Come out of the loop and perform a final operation as above with the remaining elements
        4. Add it to sum
        5. Return maxSum
    '''
    batch = 1
    maxSum = 0
    start = 0 
    end = products
    segment.sort()
    if len(segment) == products:
        maxSum += (batch * sumElem(segment[start:len(segment)]))
    else: 
        while batch != products:
            maxSum += (batch * sumElem(segment[start:end]))
            batch += 1
            start += products
            end += products
        maxSum += (batch * sumElem(segment[start:len(segment)]))
    return maxSum

# function to find the sum of the elements
def sumElem(arr):
    total = 0
    for item in arr: total += item
    return total
```

**Another Solution:**

```
def maxScore(segment, products):
    # Write your code here
    # If the segment == products, then it should return all the sum
    # We will evaluate as per the products listing requirement and find the sum
    
    '''
        Algo for else condition
        1. We will maintain a start and end pointer to keep a check till counter equals products
        2. We will keep adding the maxSum of the value [i * sum(batch of the element)]
        3. Come out of the loop and perform a final operation as above with the remaining elements
        4. Add it to sum
        5. Return maxSum
    '''
    batch = 1
    maxSum = 0
    start = 0 
    end = products
    segment.sort()
    while batch != products:
      maxSum += (batch * sumElem(segment[start:end]))
      batch += 1
      start += products
      end += products
    maxSum += (batch * sumElem(segment[start:len(segment)]))
    return maxSum

# function to find the sum of the elements
def sumElem(arr):
    total = 0
    for item in arr: total += item
    return total
```

After all the testing, the code works fine for all the visible test cases, but doesn't pass any of the hidden test cases on HackerRank. I guess there is some kind of misunderstanding happened in understanding the question, because the solution seems fine to me.

Comment: maybe you can also share the question link. I couldn't find it. is it from the ongoing contest?

Comment: Yes @shivank98, contest name is **Hack the Interview II - Global**, otherwise I would have shared the link. Anyways question is clearly written for your understanding

Comment: I am not sure but actually, in that case, it is sort of cheating that you are trying to find the answer somewhere. 
It might don't seems to follow SO policies. It was mentioned somewhere I couldn't find the link though.

Comment: I am not doing cheating, since I have solved the question by my code. It is just that I need some help on this in respect of guidance. That's all

Comment: I cannot see where you are taking the modulo. I don't know Python well, but taking modulo just at the end will not work If variable range is not large enough

Comment: Can someone please share an example where it's not optimal to first sort the values ascending and then have all segments of size `m` except the last one, and the last one (equal or greater than `m`) with all the values that are left over?

Comment: Don't forget about module result by 10^9 + 7.

Comment: That is the thing I guess, which I am not understanding, and needs help. Could you help me out on that @YerzhanTorgayev

Comment: @Alok Just do result%(10**9+7), simple mod operation.Nothing fancy.

Comment: @Alok As the output format itself says that you need to take modulo 10^9 + 7 of your answer. So, modify your return as `return maxSum % 1000000007`

Answer (score 1):

We firstly, sort the given array. This is because the numerically greater the number we "segment" in the end, it would result in a greater sum and also it would be multiplied by the index of segment which would in turn maximise the output.

The simple logic to solve the question, is to find the maximum number of segments with `m` products. As in the sample input, for the input `n=5`, `m=2`:
We can form at max 1 segment with 2 products because if we take 2 segments with 2 products, we're left with 1 product in the end, and we cannot segment that (as per the question).

In order to achieve that we divide the length of the string with `m` and subtract 1 from it, if it is not completely divisible.

```
def maxScore(a, m):

a.sort()
print(a)
x=len(a)

if x%m==0:
    y=int(x/m)
else:
    y=int(x/m)-1

summ=0
count=1
#print(y)
i=0
for _ in range(y): 
    summ=summ+(sum(a[i:i+m])*count)
    count=count+1
    i=i+m
    print(summ)

summ=summ+sum(a[i:])*count
print(summ)

return summ%1000000007
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def maxScore(a, m):
    # Write your code here

    n=len(a)
    a.sort()
    possible_quotient=n//m
    sets=possible_quotient-1
    set_range=sets*m
    base=1
    SUM=0
    k=0
    for i in range(sets):
        temp=a[k:k+m]
        k+=m
        tsum=sum(temp)*base
        SUM+=tsum
        base+=1
        i+=m
    temp2=sum(a[set_range:n])*base
    SUM+=temp2
    return(SUM%1000000007)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def maxScore(a, m):
    # Write your code here
    a.sort()
    l = len(a)
    j = 1
    s = 0
    i = 0
    while i+(2*m) <= l:
        s += sum(a[i:i+m])*j
        i += m
        j += 1
        print(s)
    s += sum(a[i:])*j
    return s%1000000007
```

This solution won't take more than 2.5 seconds!

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

try this is in php

```php
function maxScore($a, $m) {
    $b=$a;
    rsort($b);
    $segments=[];
    $nullsum=false;
    while(count($b) && !$nullsum){
        $seg=[];
        if(count($b)>=$m){
            while(!(count($seg)>=$m))
                array_push($seg,array_pop($b));
            $segments[]=$seg;
        }else{
            if(count($segments))
                while(count($b))
                    array_push($segments[count($segments)-1],array_pop($b));
            else
                $nullsum=true;
        }
    }
    $sum=0;
    for($j=0;$j<count($segments);$j++){
        $sum+= array_sum($segments[$j])*($j+1);
    }
    return $sum  % 1000000007;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Java solution:

```
class Result {

    public static final int MODULO = 1000000007;

    public static int maxScore(List<Integer> a, int m) {
        int segments = a.size() / m;
        int segmentsMod = a.size() % m;
        int maxScore = 0;
        int segmentNum = 1;
        int segmentIdx = 0;
        int segmentTotal = 0;

        for (Integer integer : a) {
            segmentTotal += integer;
            segmentIdx++;
            
            if (segmentIdx == m && segmentNum < segments) {
                maxScore += segmentTotal * segmentNum;
                segmentTotal = 0;
                segmentIdx = 0;
                segmentNum++;

            } else if (segmentNum == segments && segmentIdx == (m + segmentsMod)) {
                maxScore += segmentTotal * segmentNum;
            }
        }

        return maxScore % MODULO;
    }
}
```