# Why do these python and kotlin functions perform differently on hackerrank?

Tags: python, performance, kotlin

I am trying to solve a contest challenge on Hackerrank (Hack the Interview II - Global  Product Distribution) using Kotlin

I started getting annoyed because my code always passed on the test cases with a small number of inputs and failed on the larger ones, even timing out on one.

So I went online and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62041746/8196427) python code that solved all test cases neatly. I went as far as converting the Python code line for line into Kotlin. But my Kotlin code always retained the same poor performance as before.

These are the two pieces of code.

Python:

```py
def maxScore(a, m):

    a.sort()
    print(a)
    x=len(a)
    
    if x%m==0:
        y=int(x/m)
    else:
        y=int(x/m)-1
    
    summ=0
    count=1
    #print(y)
    i=0
    for _ in range(y): 
        summ=summ+(sum(a[i:i+m])*count)
        count=count+1
        i=i+m
        print(summ)
    
    summ=summ+sum(a[i:])*count
    print(summ)
    
    return summ%1000000007
```

Kotlin:

```kotlin
fun maxScore(a: Array<Int>, m: Int): Int {

    a.sort()

    // print(a)

    val x = a.size

    val y = if (x % m == 0) x / m
        else (x / m) - 1

    var summ = 0
    var count = 1

    // print(y)

    var i = 0

    for (s in 0 until y) {
        summ += a.sliceArray(i until (i + m)).sum() * count
        count++
        i += m
        // print(summ)
    }

    summ += a.sliceArray(i until a.size).sum() * count
    // print(summ)

    return summ % 1000000007

}
```

Is there something wrong with the code translation? How can I make the Kotlin code work on the larger test cases?

UPDATE: `copyOfRange()` performs better than `sliceArray()`. Code no longer times out on any test case, but still fails on all the large test cases

Comment: My guess is that Python optimizes `sum(array[i:i+m])` and Kotlin doesn't optimize the analogous slice and sum functions.

Comment: @Barmar Does not account for why the outputs are different for the large test cases

Comment: Juding by the documentation, `sliceArray()` seems to allocate a new array and copy stuff across, but Python probably works with references. (And there might be integer overflow, which doesn't happen in Python)

Comment: Can you clarify - is your Kotlin program just slow or does it get the wrong answers too? It doesn't seem to account for overflow in 32-bit integers, which is almost certainly tested in the later test-cases.

Answer (score 2):

There's three issues I can see here. I'll point you in the right direction for now.

1. Both the Python and the Kotlin copy the array each time. This might or might not be a problem. You have up to a million elements and each is copied only once. I'd be surprised if that exceeds your time limits but it might do. It looks like you can avoid the copy with `.subList()`.
2. It looks like you're treating the leftover items as if they're in a bin of their own. But this bin is smaller than m, which isn't allowed. Check that this is really what you intend.
3. Kotlin Ints are 32-bit signed integers. You can only store numbers up to about 2 billion before they overflow. You need to avoid this! Look at the constraints - you can have up to a million products with individual values up to a billion each. (This is different from Python ints, which never overflow, and so will always give the right answer, but can use a lot of memory and slow down if you try to do operations on really big numbers, which might well be causing your program to time out.) Here is a hint: `(a + b) % n` is equal to `((a % n) + (b % n)) % n`

Comment: the calculation of y ensures that the number of leftover items is never less than m

Comment: For the 3rd point you raised, I tried using the right-hand side of your hint when calculating summ and the performance was no different

Comment: The hint isn't a simple substitution to perform. You need to think about where in your program the numbers can overflow. Try stepping through your code with test data made up of very large numbers to understand what happens. E.g. what happens if the values of the products are 999999997, 999999998, 999999999, 1000000000? What happens if n=1000000, m=1 and every product has value 1000000000? Think about where your arithmetic can overflow and how to avoid it.